$H^1$ and $BMO$ interpoaltion on spaces of homogeneous type
In this Coifman and Weiss I've found that in spaces of homoegeneous type holds a $(H^1,L^1)-(L^p,L^p)$ interpolation theorem. (it is even stronger because it only needs weak $(H^1,1)$ and weak $(p,p)$ boundedness).
I was wandering if the classical $(L^p,L^p)-(L^\infty,BMO)$ interpolation result still holds in that context. I think that the usual proof on $\mathbb{R}^n$ could be adapted to spaces of homogeneous type. Unfortunately I cannot see this result stated anywhere, so I might be wrong.
I was also wandering if holds a  $(H^1,L^1)-(L^\infty,BMO)$ interpoaltion theorem. Also for this kind of theorem I couldn't find any reference(for this one I couldn't find any reference also for $\mathbb{R}^n$, even if I know that in that context it's true).
Can you provide me some references please?
